# Laravel sanctum API tokens with Vue header error

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, rest, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to authenticate my API route with sanctum while using vue.js but I'm getting a header error.

bootstrap.js

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  config.headers.common = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }

  return config
})
```

Getting this error

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on
> 'XMLHttpRequest': 'Bearer
> 100|paUaKhln1hiQUGWUyRshAC5fL8qS9qMhsR5n6CHd' is not a valid HTTP
> header field value.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead

```
config.headers = {
    ...config.headers,
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}
```

Comment: nope still getting the same error any other idea